# how to put search box in display tag using jsp & servlet?

Tags: displaytag

jsp code for display tag will shown below..
i want search textbox on the Complain number...

```
<display:table name="ComplainList" id="data" uid="models" pagesize="5" requestURI='<%= request.getContextPath()+"/ComplainController" %>' export="true"  >
        <display:column title='<input class="selectAll" name="selectAll"  type="checkbox"  />'><center> 
        <input  class="SelectId" name="SelectId" type="checkbox" value="<c:out value="${data.getComplainId()}"></c:out>" >
        </input></center></display:column>
        <c:set var="complainDate" value="${fn:substring(data.getComplainDate(), 0, 10)}" />
        <display:column property="complainNumber" media="html pdf excel csv"  title="Complain Number" group="1" 
        sortable="true" />
        <display:column  title="Complain Date" group="2" media="html pdf excel csv" 
            sortable="true" ><c:out value="${complainDate}"></c:out></display:column>   
        <display:column property="status" title="Status" media="html pdf excel csv" />
        <display:column title="View" ><a  title="View Record"  value="<c:out value="${data.getComplainId()}"></c:out>" onclick="viewComplain(this)" >
           <img src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath }"></c:out>/images/view.png" alt="View"></img></a></display:column>
        <display:column title="Edit"><a  title="Edit Record" href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath }"></c:out>/ComplainController?edit=<c:out value="${data.getComplainId()}"></c:out>">
            <img src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath }"></c:out>/images/edit.png" alt="Edit"></img></a></display:column>
        <display:column title="Delete"> <a title="Delete Record" href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath }"></c:out>/ComplainController?delete=<c:out value="${data.getComplainId()}"></c:out>" >
            <img src="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath }"></c:out>/images/delete.png" alt="Delete"></img></a></display`enter code here`:column>
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename"
            value="ComplainDetails.xls" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename"
            value="ComplainDetails.pdf" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename"
            value="ComplainDetails.csv" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
    </display:table>
```

the below given code is servlet code..

```
Long id = Long.parseLong(request.getSession()
                    .getAttribute("UserId").toString());
            List<Complain> complains = complainDAO.displayComplain(id);
            request.setAttribute("ComplainList", complains);
```

Any one can help me i want search box..
Advance thanks to all of you..

Answer (score 0):

Get the DisplayTag patch from this url:
https://bitbucket.org/bkumar/displaytag-search

Add it to your classpath and follow this link for implementation:
http://www.bkumar.co.uk/2012/03/12/displaytag-table-search-using-datatables-jquery-plugin/